# How to write this JavaScript code for finding if a tree is a Binary Search Tree in fewer lines?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

In a quiz for my Javascript class, we were told to make a simple tree and write a function that returns true or false whether it is a BST or not.

I got a decent grade, but i got 10 points off because the instructor said "It can be done in 6 less lines".

This is what I had:

```
function node(value, left, right){
    this.Value = value;
    this.Left = left;
    this.Right = right;
}

//this IS a BST, returns true
var head = new node(8, new node(9, null, null), new node(10, new node(9, null, null), new node(14, new node(13, null, null), null)));


function isBST(currNode){
    if(currNode.Left === null && currNode.Right === null){
        return true;
    }
    else if(currNode.Left.Value > currNode.Value || currNode.Right.Value < currNode.Value){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if(currNode.Left === null){
            return isBST(currNode.Right);
        }
        else if(currNode.Right === null){
            return isBST(currNode.Left);
        }
        else{
            return (isBST(currNode.Left) && isBST(currNode.Right));
        }
    }
}


console.log(isBST(head));
```

Anything I'm overlooking here? Maybe it shouldn't have been recursive?

Comment: Minify it and give it to them as one line... joking! The second return statement in your `else` condition is unreachable though.

Comment: @Kyle Richardson should I change it to "return isBST(currNode.Left) && isBST(currNode.Right);"

Comment: changed it. Is that better?

Comment: you could omit else parts after then parts return.

Comment: Yes it is. You could also remove curly braces from arounf if statements that are one line... like James said though... readable code > less lines. Teacher seems bad to me... You should of lost 10 points for the extraneous return, not line count.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the teacher just runs a few test cases and then glances at the code.  I guess it passed enough of the test cases for her to assume the code was right.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume the teacher isn't marking him down on using curly braces. I expect that you can greatly reduce the conditions with some careful reshuffling

Comment: @Team.Coco: Can you provide the definition of a binary search tree? Preferably from the assignment spec?

Comment: The fact that the teacher marked off for _too many lines_ and didn't even comment on an unreachable return statement says to me they didn't really even look at the code.

Comment: there wasn't an explicit definition of one on the assignment, but the way she taught it, she basically said it is a tree where the left child is always less than the parent and the right child is greater. Is that wrong?

Comment: Sure it ought to be recursive.  Boxes inside boxes, tree structures, folders/files ... => think recursion.   Here is the Tic tac box problem, an example of recursion that I wrote, if you are interested.  http://output.jsbin.com/lemusan/8/

Comment: With that definition, why is a single node with nothing to either side considered a BST?

Comment: It's not? Are BST's required to have more than one node?

Comment: I didn't say that, I'm saying with this description: "_where the left child is always less than the parent and the right child is greater_".

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean to sound snarky. I actually have no idea. I cant find anything online about minimum size for a BST or anything.

Comment: Oh I did not take you as snarky as at all! This would be a good place to look: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current function is that it does not work.  It returns true for:

```
     4
    / \
   3   5
  / \
 2  100
```

It seems that all the other answers at this time have the same problem.  Here's one that works and is a lot shorter

```
function isBST(curNode, minval, maxval){
    if (curNode == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return (
        (minval == null || minval <= curNode.Value) &&
        (maxval == null || maxval >= curNode.Value) &&
        isBST(curNode.Left, minval, curNode.Value) &&
        isBST(curNode.Right, curNode.Value, maxval)
    );
}
```

Comment: up voted, but his teacher doesn't actually look at the code to see if it works.

Comment: Why is above `[4,3,5,2,100]` not a BST? All left nodes are less than parent and all right nodes are greater than it's parent..

Comment: @maverick because that is not the whole criteria.  All the nodes left of 4 have to be less than or equal to 4, but 100 is not less than 4.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I have never seen this criteria anywhere. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-data-structure/
What you are referring to is `max-heap` data structure, which is a special case of Binary Tree. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/heap_data_structure.htm#:~:text=Min%2DHeap%20%E2%88%92%20Where%20the%20value,input%20and%20order%20of%20arrival.

Comment: @maverick let's say you are searching for 100 in a BST.  You start at the root. The root has value 4.  Will you go left or right?  Oh, look, you didn't find it because my BST is invalid!  Also, you should *read* the GFG article you linked more closely.

Comment: Its weird how these popular blogs don't mention all the conditions and just call it a day! Do you know any trust worthy resource for referring DS?

Comment: Writers are more reliable than readers, but either way, if you want to get real working knowledge, then you should prove things to yourself after reading them (or verify the proofs if given), and that will catch erroneous writings as well as misreadings.  I don't just trust anything.

Answer (score 1):

If all your teacher is worried about is line count... I would consider them to be a bad teacher...

That being said... I'm not saying your code is correct, but here is your code minus the extraneous return statement, with more than 6 less lines.

```
function node(value, left, right){
    this.Value = value;
    this.Left = left;
    this.Right = right;
}

//this IS a BST, returns true
var head = new node(8, new node(9, null, null), new node(10, new node(9, null, null), new node(14, new node(13, null, null), null)));

function isBST(currNode){
    if(currNode.Left === null && currNode.Right === null) return true;
    if(currNode.Left.Value > currNode.Value || currNode.Right.Value < currNode.Value) return false;
    if(currNode.Left === null) return isBST(currNode.Right);
    if(currNode.Right === null) return isBST(currNode.Left);
    return (isBST(currNode.Left) && isBST(currNode.Right));
}

console.log(isBST(head));
```

**As an aside**: verbose readable code trumps less lines and hard to read **99.99%** of the time. 0.01% is when you're in a bad teacher's class who cares more about line count than actually looking at your assignment.

**Aside #2**: A line more than ~80 characters in length should normally be split into multiple lines for readability. No one likes to read one long line of code.

EDIT: For a real BST modeled after the example @ [stanford.edu](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)

```
var head = new node(5,
    new node(3,
        new node(1, null, null),
        new node(4, null, null)
    ),
    new node(9,
        new node(6, null, null),
        null
    )
);
```