# Given a tree check if it is a valid BST

Tags: data-structures

Can someone please help me with where am i going wrong with the logic? 
**Question** is you are given a root of the tree you need to tell if the tree is BST or not

The  DATA value of every node in a node's left subtree is less than the data value of that node.
The DATA value of every node in a node's right subtree is greater than the data value of that node.
Given the root node of a binary tree, can you determine if it's also a binary search tree?

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
  if(root.left==null && root.right==null)
    return true;
  if(root.left!=null) {
    if(root.data<root.left.data)
      checkBST(root.left);
    else
      return false;
  }
  if(root.right!=null) {
    if(root.data>root.right.data)
      checkBST(root.right);
    else 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this question got so many downvotes, but in general try to improve the formatting of your questions after you ask them. I re-formatted the code to make it more readable and also I edited the title to reflect what you are asking for

Comment: Same answer as this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353921/how-to-write-this-javascript-code-for-finding-if-a-tree-is-a-binary-search-tree/45355179#45355179 , and your initial implementation is broken the same way.  Maybe you have the same prof.  If your prof told you that you can check a binary tree by comparing each node to its children, then please point him to that answer so he will stop making the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparisons are reversed. If this is a valid BST, the data in the root should be not less than the data in its left subtree and similarly the value in the root should be not more than the data in its right subtree.

Also note that in the statement above I have included equality - typically a BST allows for equal elements and they can be placed either on the left or on the right.

And the last most important point - if this is a valid BST, than the root should be not less than all nodes in its left subtree. You only compare the value to the root of the left subtree. However the root of the left subtree is less than all notes in ITS right subtree, so those nodes can potentially be bigger than the original root. Consider this example:

```
    10
   /
  5
 / \
3   13
```

According to your check this is a valid BST, while it is not.

Answer (score 1):

BST has the following properties.

- The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node’s key.
- The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node’s key.
- Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.

### Code

```
bool isBst(Node *node, int left = INT_MIN, int right = INT_MAX){
    if (!node)
        return true;
    if (node->data < left || node->data > right)
       return false;
    return isBst(node->left, left, node->data) 
                 && isBst(node->right, node->data, right);
}
```